# how can i apply the button function properly on the code?

Tags: javascript, java, button, click, element

need to apply a button, that will show one of the options that i defiend.

```
 let teams = ["atalanta", "Bologna", "Cremonese", "Empoli", "Fiorentina", 
"Verona", "Inter", "Juventus", "Lazio", "Lecce", "Milan", "Monza",
 "Napoli", "Roma", "Salernitana", "Sampdoria", "Sassuolo", "Spezia",
  "Torino", "Udinese"];

  let secretTeam = teams[Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)];
  console.log(secretTeam);

Element.querySelector('.search').addEventListener('.click' , function(){
const guess = (document.querySelector('.guess'));

  
    }
```

Comment: There is no button element in your code provided - you can eather create a button elemnt via javascript or attach the clikk-handler to an html-element.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding im new at this.
i created a button already inside the html,
my problem is that the button isn't working.
i wanted to create a guess program which the user guess one of those 'teams'
and the program would pick one of them randomly.
i created the button and also kind of search bar for the guess but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make the text of a button read as your secretTeam variable?  You would do that like this:

```
<script>
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.textContent = secretTeam;
    button.setAttribute('id', 'some-id');
    button.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    document.getElementById('root').appendChild(button);
</script>
```

Comment: this the code i wrote at the script

 let teams = ["atalanta", "Bologna", "Cremonese", "Empoli", "Fiorentina", 
"Verona", "Inter", "Juventus", "Lazio", "Lecce", "Milan", "Monza",
 "Napoli", "Roma", "Salernitana", "Sampdoria", "Sassuolo", "Spezia",
  "Torino", "Udinese"];

  let secretTeam = teams[Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)];
  console.log(secretTeam);

document.querySelector('.search').addEventListener('.click' , function(){
const guess = (document.querySelector('.guess'));
})

Comment: and this is my html code

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>seria a</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="guess.js"></script>
  <h1>seria a guess program</h1>  
  <input type="text" class="guess">
  <button class = "search">GO</button>
  <p class="messege">result</p>
</body>
</html>